# Get CKEDITOR.instance by parent element

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have some CKEDITOR.instances with random instance IDs. The editors are delivered via 3rd party API. I wrap the editor instances in a list like this:

```
<ul>
<li id="mykeyA">
<!-- here is the editor instance 1 with random ID-->
</li>
<li id="mykeyB">
<!-- here is the editor instance 2 with random ID-->
</li>
<li id="mykeyC">
<!-- here is the editor instance 3 with random ID-->
</li>
</ul>
```

I need to access the CKEDITOR.instance by my ID.
Something like: get *CKEDITOR.instance* placed in the LI-element with ID *mykeyB*.

I have tried this: $('#mykeyB').children[CKEDITOR.instance] But this does not work.

How do I get the instance by wrapped element?

Answer (score 0):

If someone else looks for it. This works for me

```
var editor_instance = $('#mykeyB').find('textarea')[0].name;
console.log(CKEDITOR.instances[editor_instance]);
```